# How to work with Mailgun API in CodeIgniter; Forbidden error in curl_exe()

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mailgun

I am working on CodeIgniter, I am using Mailgun API to send the emails.But I am getting FORBIDDEN while echoing curl_exe() as shown in code:

```
 <?php
Class Email3 extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function index() {
        $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';


              $ch = curl_init();
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'my-api-key');
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
                          'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages');
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                            array('from' => 'mymail',
                                  'to' => 'othermail',
                                  'subject' => 'The Printer Caught Fire',
                                  'text' => 'We have a problem.'));
              $result = curl_exec($ch);
              curl_close($ch);
              echo $result;
            }

    }


?>
```

I googled it as well searched over SO also but Unable to get solution.Please help me for this.
Also email is not been send.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple CI library you can use:

**application/libraries/Mailgun.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mailgun {

  protected $CI;
  private static $api_key;
  private static $api_base_url;

  public function __construct() {
    // assign CI super object
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    // config
    self::$api_key = "key-XXXXX";
    self::$api_base_url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com";
  }

  /**
   * Send mail
   * $mail = array(from, to, subject, text)
   */
  public static function send($mail) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . self::$api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$api_base_url . '/messages');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mail);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }

}
```

Then in your controller:

**application/controllers/Email.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Email extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {
    $this->load->library('mailgun');
    $this->mailgun::send([
      'from' => "Example.com team <no-reply@mg.example.com>",
      'to' => "somerandomuser@gmail.com",
      'subject' => "Welcome to Example.com",
      'text' => "We just want to say hi. Have fun at Example.com"
    ]);
  }

}
```

You must use a valid API key and base url for it to work.